# jQuery - dynamically created element as selector with 'eq()'

Tags: jquery, html

I've got some images and I've used jQuery to wrap each image in a `<li>`. I then want to select one of these list elements by index.

HTML

```
<div id="slider">
  <img src="..." alt="" />
  <img src="..." alt="" />
  <img src="..." alt="" />
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#slider').children().wrap('<li />');
$('#slider').wrapInner('<ul class="sliderUl" />');

var sliderLi = $('#slider').find('li');
$(sliderLi + ':eq(2)').addClass('test');
```

This doesn't work because the list elements are created dynamically, so although the variable seems to be created and work ok, it doesn't work with the 'eq'. Any ideas what else I can do?

I have to do it using the list elements as a variable.

Comment: Basically, what is `$(sliderLi + 'eq(2)')` supposed to do? `sliderLi` is a jQuery object, `"eq(2)"` is a string. Why do you expect anything meaningful to happen when adding them?

Comment: If I do $('li:eq(2)').addClass('test') that works, so why wouldn't it by making the 'li' a variable?

Comment: That's like saying that `alert(myArray.length)` works so `alert(myArray + 'length')` should also work. If you wanted to use `eq` as a string, the correct syntax would be `sliderLi.filter(':eq(2)')` -- but of course that's ugly and `sliderLi.eq(2)` is to be preferred.

Comment: Mmm yes I think I see now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are try to use `eq()` like `:eq` sliderLi is object not selector.

*Change*

```
$(sliderLi + 'eq(2)').addClass('test');
```

*To*

```
$(sliderLi).eq(2).addClass('test');
```

OR, using `:eq`

```
$('#slider').find('li:eq(2)').addClass('test');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(sliderLi).eq(2).addClass('test');
```

You can use the `:eq()` pseudo with a string selector, but `sliderLi` is a jQuery object, not a string.

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
var sliderLi = $('#slider').find('li:eq(2)');
```

or

```
var sliderLi = $('#slider li:eq(2)');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#slider').find('li:eq(2)').addClass('test');
```

Just as a note, take into account that `eq` index is zero based

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#slider li:eq(2)').addClass('test');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$(function(){
 $('#slider').children().each(function(){
    $(this).wrap('<li />');
 });
 $('#slider').wrapInner('<ul class="sliderUl" />');
 $(".sliderUl").children("li:eq(2)").addClass("test");
});
```

[**Working FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jh4VD/)