# Jquery selector over dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamic

I think this is a well known question but I cannot find an answer that satisfy me. I have a page **A** that loads a script:

```
jQuery.getScript('js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js', function (data, status, jqxhr) {
    $('table').tablesorter();
});
```

This code makes every table to be "sorteable" by header (using the Tablesorter plugin). Now my page has a link that, when pressed, calls a page **B** and insert the content via Ajax (actually they are many links that can load pages **B**, **C**, etc). Of course the tables from page **B** are not affected by the previous code, because they are loaded afterwards. How can I make the code work with dynamically created elements in a scalable way?

I have checked different questions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31562875/jquery-selector-targetting-a-dynamic-attribute-not-working), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060862/jquery-dynamically-created-element-as-selector-with-eq), [this](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/access-dynamic-generated-element-by-any-selector-dont-work) or [this](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-selector-does-not-see-elements-created-on-the-fly)), but none seems to look for my potential solution. I know about `on()`, but I am not trying to attach an event here. I could also add extra code on each page that could be loaded by Ajax, but it is error prone (I could forget to include the script in some of the pages) and seems not very scalable nor elegant. I am also a bit concerned about performance and creating lots of `on()` listeners (not sure if I should be).

How Jquery addresses this? Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
$.get('/getnewitem.aspx', function(data){
     // add to table.
     $('table').tablesorter();   // run the sorter again after adding.
});
```

Comment: This works (I would define a function instead), but doesn't it look messy,  like if it wasn't a good architectural solution? What if I have more elements to initialise? For me this solution is telling me to create a function newPage() that does all this sort of code. But it seems possible that tablesorter attaches an event twice on the old tables?